# Is it possible schedule an apex job to run several times everyday but during an interval time?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job, cron

I am quite confused about the CRON expressions. I would like to run a job several times every day but in a time interval. For example:

Every day run X job every 2 minutes from 3:00 am to 4:00 am.

If it isn't possible, is there any workaround?

Comment: This will consume 30% of your org's scheduled jobs limit, and jobs are _not_ guaranteed to go off exactly at 2-minute resolution. Consider very carefully whether you truly need this implementation pattern.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you need 30 jobs to run in that time frame.

You can schedule 30 jobs each running only once in 24 hours and each with a interval of 2 minutes.

```
DailyLeadProcessor objDailyLeadProcessor = new DailyLeadProcessor();

for (Integer i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    Integer intTime = i * 2;
    String cronExpr = '0 '+intTime+' 15 ? * * *';
    System.schedule('DailyJobRunner '+ i, cronExpr , objDailyLeadProcessor);
}
```

Basically what it will do is, create 30 schedule jobs, running every day at a specific time. But as it is in interval of 2 minutes, it will run at `3:00 3:02 3:04 3:06 ........... 3:56 3:58`, everyday.

For aborting just use:

```
List<CronTrigger> JOBIDLIST = new List<CronTrigger>();
JOBIDLIST = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name LIKE '%DailyJobRunner%'];

for(CronTrigger job:JOBIDLIST )
{
    System.abortJob(job.Id);
}
```

Comment: N.B. you're only allowed 100 jobs scheduled,  so this will consume a lot of resources.